# Codeigniter 3 Form Validation Not Working as Expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

CI3 documentation clearly states, "Since you haven’t told the Form Validation class to validate anything yet, it returns FALSE (boolean false) by default. `The run()` method only returns TRUE if it has successfully applied your rules without any of them failing.".

I have the below method snipplet.  Obviously, on first view, the view will always spit out a 'Warning - Oooops something went wrong' but with no validations_errors().  How would I go about fixing that?  Would one check to see if the form was $_POST ?  What is the best way or suggestion on how to complete?  bootstrap_alert() just wraps the error or success message into a bootstrap alert.

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $message = array(   'message'   => 'Warning - Ooops something went wrong '.validation_errors(),
                            'class'     => 'danger',  // must be warning, danger, success or info.
                    );
        $this->data['alert'] = bootstrap_alert($message);
        $this->load->view($this->mh_template, $this->data);
    }   else {
        $my_time_zone   = $this->input->post('timezones');
        $user_id        = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
        $setting_insert_or_update = 'user_time_zone';
        $this->MH_user_settings_model->mh_insert_or_update_setting($setting_insert_or_update, $my_time_zone, $user_id);
        $message = array(   'message'   => 'Success - Timezone updated',
                            'class'     => 'success',  // must be warning, danger, success or info.
                        );
        $this->data['alert'] = bootstrap_alert($message);
        $this->load->view($this->mh_template, $this->data); 
    }
```

This is what I finally ended up doing:

// set the form rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('timezones', 'timezones', 'required');

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->load->view($this->mh_template, $this->data);


    }   else {

        $my_time_zone   = $this->input->post('timezones');
        $user_id        = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
        $setting_insert_or_update = 'user_time_zone';
        $this->MH_user_settings_model->mh_insert_or_update_setting($setting_insert_or_update, $my_time_zone, $user_id);
        $message = array(   'message'   => 'Success - Timezone updated',
                            'class'     => 'success',  // must be warning, danger, success or info.
                        );
        $this->data['alert'] = bootstrap_alert($message);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->data['alert'] );              
        redirect('/MH_app_private/mh_app_settings');
    }
```

Comment: can you post your whole function so we can check left things?

Comment: have you load form_validation library?

Comment: On initial view, there are no errors, however, the message array is shown (without validation errors).  On post when I purposely make an error, the message array is show with validation errors.  Success is also show at the right time.  The problem is the initial view.  Yes, form_validation is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Check if is the request is POST to show or not to show the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize I could format the validation_errors() with something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

This is finally what solved the issue.

Comment: I am curious about how this solve the problem. Could you show?